# display multiple rows from oracle database with php

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to display multiple rows from Oracle table with php.
Below is my code:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php"); 
$personcon=$conn;

$surname = $_POST['Surname'];   
$suburb = $_POST['Suburb'];
$state = $_POST['State'];
$discipline = $_POST['Discipline'];
$companyname = $_POST['CompanyName'];
$rank = $_POST['Rank'];
$role = $_POST['Role'];
$yearsexperience = $_POST['YearsExperience'];
$recentproject = $_POST['RecentProject'];
$sellrate = $_POST['SellRate'];
$projectnumber = $_POST['ProjectNumber'];
$tendernumber = $_POST['TenderNumber'];

$query = "SELECT CP.ROLE AS CURRENT_ROLE , CP.SURNAME, CP.FIRSTNAME, CP.COMPANY,CC.COMPANYNAME AS CONSULTANT_COMPANY, CP.YEARSEXPERIENCE AS EXPERIENCE_IN_YEAR, CP.QUALIFICATION, D.PRINCIPLEDISCIPLINE, D.SUBDISCIPLINE1, D.SUBDISCIPLINE2, D.SUBDISCIPLINE3, D.SUBDISCIPLINE4, D.SUBDISCIPLINE5, D.SUBDISCIPLINE6,  D.SUBDISCIPLINE7,  D.SUBDISCIPLINE8,  L.SUBURB, L.STATE, L.COUNTRY FROM CONSULTANTPERSONNEL CP, LOCATION L, ONSULTANTPERSONNEL_DISCIPLINE N, DISCIPLINE D, CONSULTANTCOMPANY CC, CONTRACTS C, PROJECTS P, TENDERS T, FEEBASIS F WHERE CP.LOCATIONID = L.LOCATIONID AND CP.CONSULTANTPERSONALID = N.CONSULTANTPERSONALID AND N.DISCIPLINID = D.DISCIPLINID AND CP.CONSULTANTCOMPANYID = CC.CONSULTANTCOMPANYID AND CP.CONTRACTID = C.CONTRACTID AND C.FEECODE = F.FEECODES AND C.PROJECTNUMBER = P.PROJECTNUMBER AND C.TENDERNUMBER = T.TENDERNUMBER AND LOWER(CP.SURNAME) LIKE LOWER('%".$surname."%') AND LOWER(L.SUBURB) LIKE LOWER('%".$suburb."%') AND LOWER(L.STATE) LIKE LOWER('%".$state."%') AND LOWER(D.PRINCIPLEDISCIPLINE) LIKE LOWER('%".$discipline."%') AND LOWER(CC.COMPANYNAME) LIKE LOWER('%".$companyname."%') AND LOWER(CP.RANK) LIKE LOWER('%".$rank."%') AND LOWER(CP.ROLE) LIKE LOWER('%".$role."%') AND LOWER(P.PROJECTNAME) LIKE LOWER('%".$recentproject."%') AND LOWER(P.PROJECTNUMBER) LIKE LOWER('%".$projectnumber."%') AND LOWER(T.TENDERNUMBER) LIKE LOWER('%".$tendernumber."%')";

$SQL = oci_parse($personcon, $query);
oci_execute($SQL);
$results = array();
$numRows = oci_fetch_all($SQL, $results, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

        if($numRows > 0){       
        echo "<p> <table border=1>\n";
            //Print the headings
            echo "<tr>\n";
                foreach($results[0] as $index=>$value)
                    echo "<th>$index</th>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";

            echo "<tr>\n";
            foreach($results as $row)
                foreach($row as $index=>$value)
                    echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        echo "</table>\n </p>";

        oci_close($personcon);
        } else {
            echo "<tr> The search you enter is not in the database.";
        }
?>
```

I can retrieve the data I wish but instead of displaying row by row, it displays all the data in one row.

Any Idea how to fix that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got simple and common (for me at least) mistake in Your loops, that creates only one row and puts every column inside. Try changing:

```
       echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach($results as $row)
            foreach($row as $index=>$value)
                echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
```

to something like this:

```
       foreach($results as $row)
       {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            foreach($row as $index=>$value)
            {
                echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
       }
```

The brackets will help You see the scopes. Its not python, You know. ;)

Comment: Thank you. It was the problem and found out later.
Thinking too much and forget to put the brackets.
Anyway thank you for looking up my messy codes and point out the error.

Comment: No problem. If You solved the problem You can write Your own answer here and accept it. or mark my as correct answer - so no one else would be bothered by it...

Comment: Yes sure. I would do that next time.